# Did Sith Eternal Army cultists survive Exegol in "The Rise of Skywalker?"

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

At the climax of *Star Wars: Episode IX - The Rise of Skywalker*, Kylo Ren arrives at Exegol after Rey and manages to assist her in fighting the Emperor.

When Kylo Ren first descends into the bowels of Exegol’s structure, he encounters multiple “hooded cultists,” who Star Wars has identified as cultists of what is called “The Sith Eternal Army” or “Sith Eternal.” These cultists are working on random machinery and scurry away. They are also far removed from an arena-full of Sith who patiently wait behind a veil to cheer on their Emperor Palpatine in his fight against Rey.

Eventually, Kylo makes his long trek to the “Jedi dueling pit” where the large convocation of Sith Eternal cultists are watching the fight. Palpatine is defeated in a massive explosion of Force-energy or feedback, and this explosive wave appears to wipe out the arena-full of hooded cultists.

Did that explosion wipe out all of the cultists on Exegol, including ones not watching the fight in arena bleachers?

Comment: Given the history of SW, surely the only answer can be "it's too early to say" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### They ded.

A considerable number of Sith disciples were killed in the temple explosion.

> The Sith throne shattered. The ceiling bouldered down around her,
> crushing thousands of disciples in the amphitheater.
>
> <sub><sup>[Rise of Skywalker: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

The planet was ultimately left an uninhabitable ruin.

> “I’m certain of it,” Finn said, scanning the horizon from the
> viewport. Debris was falling everywhere. **Exegol was going to be a
> wasteland after this. Not that it had been paradise to begin with. But
> all those Star Destroyers were going to smolder for years.**

The attack resulted in the **total annihilation** of the Sith Eternal cult.

> **SITH ETERNAL:** The resurrected Emperor Palpatine and **the entirety of
> the Sith Eternal cult were wiped out in the battle.** Alongside them,
> General Pryde and the crew of the Steadfast all perished.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy)</sup></sub>

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - Oh sure. It only takes a stroke of the writer's pen to make it so that *some* of them survived, unbeknownst to the rest of the galaxy. They were off-planet at the time or the Emperor had a second secret Sith sanctuary stashed somewhere.

Comment: Yet Palpatine returns....  (in a future trilogy)